# Rails FormBuilder subclass and translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, translation, subclass, formbuilder

I'm building a FormBuilder in Rails that is supposed to produce materializecss compliant checkboxes as shown in https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html

Basically I'm looking for a method `def check_box_with_label(name)` that produces something like:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>TRANSLATED LABEL FOR NAME AS DEFINED IN TRANSLATION</span>
</label>
```

My problem is to fill the inner span with the translated version. Using label_tag etc. does not use the translation. The translation is located in separate YML files, partly provided by devise-i18n. I cannot find any documentation regarding translation issues inside a FormBuilder subclass. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

After severe fiddeling, I found that the following approach works. However I'm not sure if it's elegant or not. It seems to work at all places I'm using it though.

The solution is to use the `@object_name` available in the FormBuilder parent class in order to look up the translation at the correct location.

```
# app/helpers/materialize_form_builder.rb
class MaterializeFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def check_box_with_label(name)
    return %Q(<label>#{check_box(name)}<span>#{tr(name)}</span></label>).html_safe
  end

  private

  def tr(name)
    I18n.t(name, scope: [:activerecord, :attributes, @object_name])
  end
end
```